# I'm trying to assign a label to a button using a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm reading through a playlist and trying to capture the title info for each item in the playlist and assign the title to a button in a grid made up of buttons.  The goal is to create something like an electronic program guide that the user would click on and have the button change what is playing in the main playback window.  I've included my current code below.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
<div align="Center" id="playerContainer">
 <div id="nowplaying"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("nowplaying").setup({
 playlist: "http://content.jwplatform.com/feeds/MFPT0wUf.rss",
 image: "http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/Wf8BfcSt-640.jpg",
 width: "580",
 height: "370",
 primary: "html5",
 advertising: { 
  client: "vast",
  tag: "http://demo.tremorvideo.com/proddev/vast/vast2RegularLinear.xml"
  }
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var items = jwplayer().ge
tPlaylist(),
      allButtons = ''; //empty str
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      console.log(items.title);
    var singleButton = '<div class="buttons01"><button type="button">' + items[i].title + '</button></div>';
    allButtons += singleButton; 
    console.log(singleButton);
    // console.log(allButtons);
}
   </script>


</div>

<p></p>
```

I'd like to be able to automatically change the label of each button below by inserting the "title" value from the play list above into the "Title # Goes Here" space below.

```
<div class="buttons">

<div class="buttons01">
<button id="Video01" align="center">Title 1 Goes Here</button>
<button id="Video02" align="center">Title 2 Goes Here</button>
<button id="Video03" align="center">Title 3 Goes Here</button>
<button id="Video04" align="center">Title 4 Goes Here</button>
<button id="Video05" align="center">Title 5 Goes Here</button>
<button id="Video06" align="center">Title 6 Goes Here</button>
</div>

<div class="buttons02">
<button id="Video01" align="center">Title 7 Goes Here</button>
<button id="Video02" align="center">Title 8 Goes Here</button>
<button id="Video03" align="center">Title 9 Goes Here</button>
<button id="Video04" align="center">Title 10 Goes Here</button>
<button id="Video05" align="center">Title 11 Goes Here</button>
<button id="Video06" align="center">Title 12 Goes Here</button>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Aren't you already assigning the title here: `var singleButton = '<div class="buttons01"><button type="button">' + items[i].title + '</button></div>';` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're doing, your code is kind of a mess but maybe...

```
var items = jwplayer().getPlaylist();
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("buttons0"+i).innerHTML = items[i].title;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I've tried implementing your code but I keep getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" at the line containing "  document.getElementById('Video0'+i).innerHTML = items[i].title;".  I tried using your code verbatim but I got the same error. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @AndrePina - I'll be happy to give you pointers, but your code the way you posted doesn't make any sense. Please make a jsfiddle and post the link, then I'll take a peek.

Comment: Hello Pamblam.  I totally appreciate your offer of help. I'm a self taught programmer (isn't it obvious).  I created a jsfiddle for your review.  Any input is appreciated.  https://jsfiddle.net/aapina/cm28vac6/1/